# python limit results to one instance (sending discord embed)

Tags: python, discord, conditional-statements, embed

So I'm working on a discord bot command that accepts an arg, searches a database and then requests information from an API and returns the information in an embed. the command should return one of three embeds. One for an exact match from database, one for a partial match from database and one for a result of no match.

the exact match, and no match work as expected. The partial match works, however it will send the embed for each item i.e if you requested "Safe" it would return the results for (and send an embed for) safe, safety boots, safety glasses, safety vest etc. etc,

as that not only clutters up the channel, and as the partial match embed already lists those items and advises user to be more specific this is redundant.

I believe it's something to do with the conditional statements but can't quite figure it out. cleaned up version of code below, please let me know if you need anything else, it's been plaguing me for days.

````
async def item4(ctx, *, arg,):
 ''' Keep best model so far '''
 matches = itemapi.search_api(arg) #returns either exact match, partial match or no match. works as expected.
 for k in matches:
  cnumber = (len(matches.keys())) #counts number of matches
  if cnumber == 1:
    if cnumber >= 2: 
        continue
    else: 
     #sends discord embed for correct match, works as expected
  elif cnumber >= 2:
    if cnumber == 0: 
      continue
    else:
     # sends discord embed for partial match BUT sends 1 embed for each match, should be 1 embed total
 else:
   if 'cnumber' in locals(): 
       pass
   else: 
    #sends discord embed for no match, works as expected ```
````

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume that when a partial match is found, that `matches` always has multiple items in it. Your for loop goes through every key in `matches` and `cnumber` never changes value. So when a partial match is found, `cnumber >= 2` will evaluate to `True` for every match and the code block will be run. The simplest way to fix this is just to break out of the loop once your embed is sent, since no matter the case you only want 1 embed to send.

Another suggestion, your for loop logic could be a little cleaner. For example in this code excerpt:

```
if cnumber == 1:
    if cnumber >= 2: 
        continue
    else: 
        #sends discord embed for correct match, works as expected
```

You are checking to see if `cnumber == 1` then checking if `cnumber >= 2`, but this logically not possible. `cnumber` cannot both equal 1 and be greater than 2, so you can just remove that code entirely. You do something similar here:

```
elif cnumber >= 2:
    if cnumber == 0: 
      continue
    else:
     # sends discord embed...
```

`cnumber` cannot be greater than 2 and equal 0. You can clean the code and it should like this:

```
for k in matches:
  cnumber = (len(matches.keys())) #counts number of matches
  if cnumber == 1:
     # sends discord embed for correct match
  elif cnumber >= 2:
     # sends discord embed for partial
     # you can add a break statement after the embed is sent to exit the loop
 else:
   if 'cnumber' in locals(): 
       pass
   else: 
    # sends discord embed for no match
```

Hopefully this helps